# If App running, start login activity else splash activity

Tags: android, android-activity

## Update

I changed the logic as pointed out by @dunnololz in his answer. But now Splash always appears when clicking on launcher icon even though application is running. *I was hoping first time when app is not running splash would show otherwise login activity show but this is not happening.*

Here is my code:

manifest splash launcher activity:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.Splash"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Splash.Java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  startService(new Intent(Splash.this, IMService.class));

  setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

  Thread background = new Thread() {
    public void run() {

      try {
        // Thread will sleep for 3 seconds
        sleep(3 * 1000);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Login.class);
        // intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        startActivity(intent);

        finish();

      } catch (Exception e) {

      }
    }
  };

  // start thread
  background.start();
}
```

---

I am using [this gist](https://gist.github.com/steveliles/11116937) to determine whether app is running or not. I found it via [this tutorial](http://steveliles.github.io/is_my_android_app_currently_foreground_or_background.html). So that class uses `Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` for API level 14+ which is what I need.

What I want to do is:

- If application is running either in foreground or background, start login activity
- If application is not running, start splash activity

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Splash.class);

  if (Foreground.get(this).isForeground()
      || Foreground.get(this).isBackground()) {

    intent = new Intent(EntryPoint.this, Login.class);
  }

  startActivity(intent);
  finish();
}
```

And here is my application class:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {    

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Foreground.init(this);
    }

}
```

Of course I have added my app to manifest file as well:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApp"
```

The **problem** is that `Splash` activity is never started. It is the `Login` activity which is always started.

I just want to be able to do this:

- If application is running either in foreground or background, start login activity
- If application is not running, start splash activity

But not sure how to get this working, I might be missing something obvious here. Or even it might be that my requirement of `either in foreground or background` is wrong as I am new to Android.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Note that the implementation of `isForeground()` and `isBackground()` are implemented as the inverse of the **same variable**. This means that `Foreground.get(this).isForeground() || Foreground.get(this).isBackground()` will **always** return true. The problem with the logic is that in order for this code to run, your application needs to be running, therefore when your condition is evaluated, your application is always running.

Comment: @idunnololz: You mean `Background` class has bug in implementation ? How do I modify code ? Can you answer plz ?

Comment: I'm not saying there is a bug in the implementation. I'm saying that there is a fundamental logical error in this code. If you want to check if the application is running before, you can't check the state of the current application because of course the application is running when you do the check.

Comment: @idunnololz: Oh I get your point. Is there anything we can modify to fix this ?

Comment: There is a solution that is being used by most applications with splash screens however it does not do exactly what you want, but it works well. I'll post an answer describing it.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to do anything as this behavior is already the default in Android.

Comment: @idunnololz: So there is no solution to this ? I see WeChat and some other apps do it. May be I need to do more research. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67257/discussion-between-idunnololz-and-dev01).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally in Android it is not advised to determine behavior based on whether the app is currently being kept in memory or not. That is what the OS should be concerned about and not something you want to concern yourself about.

In the current version of Android (since I'm not sure if this behavior is true for older versions), when you tap an app to launch it, the OS checks to see if the app is already "open". If it is, it restores the state of the "open" app. If the app is not already "open", Android will launch the activity that is marked at the launcher. So the solution to this problem is simply to let Android handle it. Make a splash activity and mark it as the launcher in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. Then have the launcher open your login activity after some time.

Now, if the app is already open, Android simply will restore the last open activity. Otherwise it will show the launcher.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I will modify code to do so. Thanks

Comment: It is not working the way you have said. Please see my update.